# Assign face value to cards in python

Tags: python

I made my code but I have a hard time figuring out how to put values to my deck? I have done some research online but I still can't figure out how to do it. I keep getting errors. How do I get face values for cards? 2-10 and 10 for KQJ and 11 for A? I have tried creating a class for it and it's not working. I'm stuck.

Comment: What problems are you experiencing? What errors do you see?

Comment: You forgot `10` from your ranks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to assign a value to each rank.

```
>>> ranks = map(str, range(2, 10+1)) + list("JQKA")
>>> values = range(2, 10+1) + [10, 10, 10, 11]
>>> print ranks
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
>>> print values
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11]

>>> d = dict(zip(ranks, values))
>>> d['K']
10
>>> d['5']
5
>>> d['A']
11
```